# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'path'

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, methods

i am new to python and i have this problem that i can't understand

```py
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'path'
```

```py
class extractor:
    """This class will find the path for the pdx"""

    def __init__(self, pdx_name,path):
        self.pdx_name = pdx_name
        self.path = path

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pdx_name

    def find_folder(self):
       if os.path.exists(self.path):
           return self.path
```

maybe someone can explain what is happening, i think it's something simple that i still did not understood.

Thank you!f

Comment: These forms of functions belong in a class -- not stand alone. That is your error.

Comment: How are you using your extractor class? I think you need to add a code snippet showing its use, at the least. When does your error occur?

Answer (score 2):

As @dawg mentioned, these methods belong in a class:

```py
import os

class File
    def __init__(self, pdx_name, path):
        self.pdx_name = pdx_name
        self.path = path

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pdx_name

    def find_folder(self):
       if os.path.exists(self.path):
           return self.path


file = File('some_name', '/Users/bob')
print(file.find_folder())
```

Comment: I think he already put those methods inside `extractor` class but smh failed to put them inside code sample

Comment: @RustamGarayev, ah, well that'll confuse everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

[in the project i have a main program and one that contain the class and i call the class in the main program if this helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYFHz.png)

This is the code inside the main python file where i call the class

import path as pt

```
val = input("Introduceti numele PDX-ului: ")
path='x'
x=pt.extractor(val,path)
print(x)
y = pt.extractor.find_folder(path)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking the OS using

`os = platform.system()`

you are overwriting the os name with a string and when it tries to use it as a module it gives error because it's a string object now.

Try to change the "`os`" to any other variable name and your problem will be solved.

Eg. `os_name = platform.system()`